# Carbon locale not respected?

Tags: php, laravel, locale, php-carbon

In my Laravel 6 app, I have `Carbon::now()->locale()` returning `it` as it should be.

As confirmation that the locale is loaded, `Carbon::now()->monthName` correctly outputs `febbraio`.

BUT `Carbon::now()->format('F')` and `Carbon::now()->formatLocalized('%B')` both return the english version `February`.

Why does the first function output the correct localized month while the others do not?

Comment: Out of curiosity why use `'F'` in `format` and `'%B'` in `formatLocalized` I thought they took the same symbols

Comment: `format()` use native `DateTime` function so it's not localized

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently, `formatLocalized()` is somehow deprecated or not working as intended.

From the Carbon docs:

> You also may know formatLocalized() method from Carbon 1. This method still works > the same in Carbon 2 but you should better use isoFormat() instead.

`Carbon::now()->isoFormat('MMMM')` is working as intended and correctly returns `febbraio`.